# Making "Figure 1" bold breaks references to it

Tags: graphics, captions

I have a figure with a caption. Normally, the caption shows up as `Figure 1 MyCaption`. However, I want the "Figure 1" part to be in bold. I found the answer to this on this website; the fix is to use `\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=md]{caption}`. However, references to the figure do not work anymore. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
The picture is shown in Figure \ref{pic}.

\begin{figure} \label{pic}
    \caption{The Picture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\label` instructions must come *after*, not before `\caption` instructions. This issue is entirely separate from whether or not the `caption` package is loaded.

Comment: @Mico Thanks, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Oh, dear, seems that Mico's comment and my answer crossed.  Will delete...